# Is it possible to integrate Bugzilla's calendar with Thunderbird when using mandatory (not visible anonymously) products

Tags: bugzilla, thunderbird

Is it possible to integrate Bugzilla's callendar with Thunderbird Lightning addon when using mandatory (not visible anonymously) products? So the user experience is the same as with Google calendar.

The problem is that Lightning would need to know the password of Bugzilla's server (which I am happy to provide).

---

BTW, searching with Google queries like "bugzilla lightning integration" is really difficult, since one get a lot of irrelevant Bugzilla bug reports of stray products...